# Centos 8 microk8s Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503

Tags: kubernetes, centos, kubectl, microk8s, coredns

I have installed microk8s on my centos 8 operating system.

```
kube-system   coredns-7f9c69c78c-lxm7c                  0/1 Running            1          18m
kube-system   calico-node-thhp8                         1/1 Running            1          68m
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-f7868dd95-dpsnl   0/1 CrashLoopBackOff   23         68m
```

When I do microk8s enable dns, coredns or calico-kube-controllers cannot be started as above.
Describe the pod for coredns :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------          ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       14m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-7f9c69c78c-lxm7c to localhost.localdomain
  Normal   Pulled          14m                 kubelet            Container image "coredns/coredns:1.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         14m                 kubelet            Created container coredns
  Normal   Started         14m                 kubelet            Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy       11m (x22 over 14m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Normal   SandboxChanged  2m8s                kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          2m7s                kubelet            Container image "coredns/coredns:1.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         2m7s                kubelet            Created container coredns
  Normal   Started         2m6s                kubelet            Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy       2m6s                kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.1.102.132:8181/ready": dial tcp 10.1.102.132:8181: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy       9s (x12 over 119s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Describe the pod for calico-kube-controllers :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling        73m                  default-scheduler  no nodes available to schedule pods
  Warning  FailedScheduling        73m (x1 over 73m)    default-scheduler  no nodes available to schedule pods
  Warning  FailedScheduling        72m (x1 over 72m)    default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled               72m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-kube-controllers-f7868dd95-dpsnl to localhost.localdomain
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  72m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "f3ea36b003b0c9142ae63fee31531f9102e40ab837f4d795d1efb5c85af223ec": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  71m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "a1c405cdcebe79c586badcc8da47700247751a50ef9a1403e95fc4995485fba0": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  71m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "4adb07610eef0d7a618105abf72a114e486c373a02d5d1b204da2bd35268dd1b": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  71m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "96aac009175973ac4c20034824db3443b3ab184cfcd1ed23786e539fb6147796": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  71m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "79639a18edcffddbdb93492157af43bb6c1f1a9ac2af1b3fbbac58335737d5dc": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  70m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "3264f006447297583a37d8cc87ffe01311deaf2a31bf25867b3b18c83db2167d": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  70m                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "5c5cf6509bfcf515ad12bc51451e4c385e5242c4f7bb593779d207abf9c906a4": error getting ClusterInformation: resource does not exist: ClusterInformation(default) with error: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org "default" not found
  Normal   Pulling                 70m                  kubelet            Pulling image "calico/kube-controllers:v3.13.2"
  Normal   Pulled                  69m                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "calico/kube-controllers:v3.13.2" in 50.744281789s
  Normal   Created                 69m                  kubelet            Created container calico-kube-controllers
  Normal   Started                 69m                  kubelet            Started container calico-kube-controllers
  Warning  Unhealthy               69m (x2 over 69m)    kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Failed to read status file status.json: open status.json: no such file or directory
  Warning  MissingClusterDNS       37m (x185 over 72m)  kubelet            pod: "calico-kube-controllers-f7868dd95-dpsnl_kube-system(d8c3ee40-7d3b-4a84-9398-19ec8a6d9082)". kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.
  Warning  Unhealthy               31m (x6 over 32m)    kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Failed to read status file status.json: open status.json: no such file or directory
  Normal   Pulled                  30m (x4 over 32m)    kubelet            Container image "calico/kube-controllers:v3.13.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 30m (x4 over 32m)    kubelet            Created container calico-kube-controllers
  Normal   Started                 30m (x4 over 32m)    kubelet            Started container calico-kube-controllers
  Warning  BackOff                 22m (x42 over 32m)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   SandboxChanged          10m                  kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Unhealthy               9m36s (x6 over 10m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Failed to read status file status.json: open status.json: no such file or directory
  Normal   Pulled                  8m51s (x4 over 10m)  kubelet            Container image "calico/kube-controllers:v3.13.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 8m51s (x4 over 10m)  kubelet            Created container calico-kube-controllers
  Normal   Started                 8m51s (x4 over 10m)  kubelet            Started container calico-kube-controllers
  Warning  BackOff                 42s (x42 over 10m)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

I cannot start my microk8s services. I don't encounter these on my Ubuntu server. What can I do in these error situations that I encounter for my Centos 8 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating the microk8s version?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).